# Cannot get service to start on chef because of a dollar sign

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to start a service that has a dollar string in its name using Chef, but I cannot. The sting is inside a variable  and I don’t know how to escape the dollar sign (I would if it was just a string)

I have looked at a info about verbatim strings and interpolation but I am unable to figure it out

The block would be:

```
code <<-EOH
sc config #{node.recipe_name.serviceName} depend= OtherService
EOH
```

And the service name would be something like Application.Instance$ABC

Somehow the $ABC part always disappears when invoking the recipe from Chef, failing to start the service.

Comment: Did you try escaping the the dollar sign with a backslash?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841165/using-the-character-in-ruby-block-in-chef

Comment: The problem is that I don’t create the string, it’s in a variable that gets the info from the result of a cmd, I don’t know how to escape the contents of the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`Shellwords.shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) (or its alias, `Shellwords.escape`) to escape your string:

```
code <<-EOH
sc config #{Shellwords.escape(node['recipe_name']['serviceName'])} depend= OtherService
EOH
```